# RAD Calendar in Weekly Mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, telerik, rad-controls

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 Application in which I need to display Rad Calendar in Weekly mode instead of monthly mode. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this unless you contact them to add this feature.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking the same.